# two nav bars with different css functions causes nav bar color change on scrolling not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu button inside of an existing navbar with a color-changing effect when scrolling. (from transparent to green color)
the menu button is actually a second navbar which opens up when pressing it.
when it opens the entire page is moving to the side like an open book (aka as Diagonal shaped NAVBAR) and the 
overflow becomes hidden so that the user will only be able to use the newly opened menu but the website will be locked until you exit the menu
the problem is, that when the user is not opening the menu and just scrolling down the website, the color of navbar is not changing. now, when I'm disabling the diagonal navbar code it is working perfectly fine. but together it's not working. the problem is the `$(window).scroll` method doesn't respond to the webpages original scrollbar when on normal view

the entire code for the diagonal navbar link: https://deepakdm.com/awesome-diagonal-shaped-navigation-bar-html-css-js/

I did change it a bit in order to suit my website...

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.bg-light').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop())
});

(function() {
  var nav = $('.diaognal-nav'),
    menu = $('.diaognal-nav h1'),
    main = $('main'),
    open = false,
    hover = false;

  menu.on('click', function() {
    open = !open ? true : false;
    nav.toggleClass('menu-active');
    main.toggleClass('menu-active');
    nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
    main.removeClass('menu-hover');
    console.log(open);
  });
  menu.hover(
    function() {
      if (!open) {
        nav.addClass('menu-hover');
        main.addClass('menu-hover');
      }
    },
    function() {
      nav.removeClass('menu-hover');
      main.removeClass('menu-hover');
    }
  );

})();
```

```css
main {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

main section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*padding: 1em 4em;*/
  /* max-width: 680px;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>

<body class="body-back">
  <nav class="menu-activea diaognal-nav">
    <h1>MENU</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>GALLERY</li>
      <li>TEAM</li>
      <li>SERVICES</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>WORK</li>
      <li>FAQ</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container menu-donate">
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="manueItems">
              <li class="menuLI"><img src="~/images/mix-logo-with-name.png" style="width:100px; height:auto; margin-left:530%;"></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML for the navbar and the menu button

Comment: yeah sure, its done

Comment: why all the break tags at the bottom?

Comment: it is just an example it's not the actual code..to show there is an ability to scroll down